# Hand-writing annotations on Keynote or PDF slides

Tags: macos, software-recommendation, pdf, keynote, handwriting

For teaching purposes I would like to be able to handwrite on slides as I give a presentation, ideally with a Wacom graphics tablet which I already own commented to my Mac running Big Sur 11.4.

Powerpoint would work really well for this, unfortunately I am using Keynote to make the slides because I need the LaTeX support which Powerpoint doesn't have. So in particular I can't easily convert these slides to Powerpoint.

In Preview, I can annotate the document but only when it's not in Presentation mode. I also can convert them to PDF, though - that’s a bit of a hassle.

Is there a good way to annotate slides during a presentation for either a Keynote or PDF presentation?

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative, if you have an iOS device, it can be used as a remote to highlight and mark up slides during presentation.

From the [Apple Docs](https://support.apple.com/guide/keynote/use-a-remote-tan85f5c958c/11.1/mac/11.4):

> If you’re using Keynote Remote to control a presentation from iPhone or iPad, you can draw on your device and have your drawing appear on the device that’s playing your presentation. This feature is useful, for example, if you want to emphasize a particular item on your slide—you can underline or circle the item for your audience.

[image: Keynote remote markup slide]

Answer (score 0):

Preview has a sketch function that you can use to “write” after a fashion.

I don’t possess a wacom graphics tablet so no idea how it would perform with that.

Answer (score 0):

[Présentation.app](http://iihm.imag.fr/blanch/software/osx-presentation/) and [SlidePilot](https://www.slidepilotapp.com/) support live annotations that don't change the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

[Presentify](https://presentify.compzets.com), i believe allows what you want and works with Keynote. Available from the MacApp Store.